# Swagger, API Gateway using AWS Cloudformation

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, swagger-2.0

I am deploying a API which is mapped to a loadbalancer. I could test the API successfully on the console but while using the invoke link in the stage, I am getting a 403. The ELB is a http end point and the invoke url is https which is normal I would say.

Also if I use the ELB DNS Name, I could get the desired result. Looks like requests are not going through API Gateway.

I am doing all of this using Cloudformation and swagger. Here is the relevant part

```
  EmployeeApi:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      BodyS3Location:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      Key: "swagger.yaml"

  EmployeeApiDeployment:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:      
      RestApiId: !Ref EmployeeApi

  EmployeeApiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    Properties:
      DeploymentId: !Ref EmployeeApiDeployment
      RestApiId: !Ref EmployeeApi
      StageName: dev
      Variables:
        employeeELB:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            !Sub ${NetworkStackName}-ELB

  EmployeeApiUsagePlan:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::UsagePlan
    Properties: 
      ApiStages: 
        - ApiId: !Ref EmployeeApi
          Stage: !Ref EmployeeApiStage      
      UsagePlanName: Basic

  EmployeeApiKey:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::ApiKey
    Properties:
      Name: employee-api-key
      Enabled: true
      StageKeys:
        - RestApiId: !Ref EmployeeApi
          StageName: !Ref EmployeeApiStage
```

Relevant part of my swagger file is

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
version: 1.0.0
title: employee-service
description: Welcome to API documentation of Employee Service

schemes:
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  api_key:
    type: apiKey
    name: x-api-key
    in: header
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  RequestValidator:
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: true
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: RequestValidator

paths:
  /employees:
    get:

      security:
        - api_key: []
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: "200"
      uri: http://${stageVariables.employeeELB}/employees
      passthroughBehavior: when_no_match
      httpMethod: GET
      contentHandling: "CONVERT_TO_TEXT"
      type: http_proxy
```

Comment: How do you use the invoke link? Using `curl`? What are the exact error messages?

Comment: I am using Postman to invoke. I am getting a 403 Forbidden with a html body which is Generated by CloudFront. The content says, The request could not be satisfied

Comment: So you using edge-optimized api gateway? Also there is no mapping shown in the code you possted? How do you map your domain to the api endpoint?

Comment: I haven't explicitly specified edge-optimized, I guess that is default. I am mapping using stageVariables. Please have a look at the swagger file and EmployeeApiStage

Comment: I just wondering where did CloudFront come from if your api is not edge-optimized?

Comment: It is edge optimized. I haven't specified it in my Cloudformation template but it was created that way

Comment: Good it got clarified. The error comes from the CF as per your error message. What about the mapping? What do you mean by that? I understand that you have custom domain with your own ssl cert mapped to the edge-optmized api endpoint?